# Не отображается страница, указанная в шаблоне компонента

Tags: angular

Есть страница Index.html, в которой рендерится компонент:

```
<body class="m-a-1">
    <app> </app>
</body>
```

Есть app.component:

```
import { Component } from 
"@angular/core";
@Component({
selector: 'app',
template: '<store></store>'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

Есть также store.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from 
"@angular/core";
import { Product } from 
"../model/product.model";
import { ProductRepository } from 
"../model/product.repository";
   @Component({
        selector: "store",
        moduleId: module.id,
        templateUrl: 
"store.component.html"
   })
    export class StoreComponent { }
```

Ну и соответственно store.component.html:

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
      <a class="navbar-brand">SPORTS STORE</a>
   </div>
```

Проблема в том, что у меня не подгружается `template: '<store></store>` в app.component и собственно store.html-страница. Что не так сделано?

Comment: `app.module.ts` покажите

Comment: import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { StoreModule } from "./store/store.module";

@NgModule({
 imports: [BrowserModule, StoreModule],
 declarations: [AppComponent],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

Comment: а `StoreModule` покажите

Comment: import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { ModelModule } from "../model/model.module";
import { StoreComponent } from "./store.component";

@NgModule({
    imports: [ModelModule, BrowserModule, FormsModule],
    declarations: [StoreComponent],
    exports: [StoreComponent]
})
export class StoreModule { }

Comment: не вижу ошибки...можете минимальный пример воспроизвести на [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)? (и ссылку сюда дайте)